Why doesn't language model generate syntactically correct LEAN 4 proof?
I am using various versions of deepseek-prover-v1.5 to generate solutions to MiniF2F problems. I must have generated hundreds of solutions, but none of them even compiles (some of these solutions look promising, but still follows the grammar of LEAN 3). On the other hand, the trainers of the model claims a 60% accuracy on 1000 pass. What did I do wrong?
I tried DeepSeek-Prover-V1.5-Base, its two quantized versions, and DeepSeek-Prover-V1.5-RL. In the case of the quantized models, I tried generating 200 answers for several problems. I expected to see at least 1 correct solution that compiles in LEAN 4. All these models do not generate correct solutions to miniF2F problems. For the multi-pass using quantized models, most of the time the answers are repeating itself in LEAN 3 syntax.

MiniF2F problems and Lean 4 require strict adherence to syntax and semantics. Many models trained on Lean 3 datasets struggle to adapt to Lean 4 without fine-tuning or additional post-processing. Also quantized models trade off some precision for efficiency, which can degrade performance. If you rely on quantized models, their output might be more prone to grammatical errors or repetitive solutions, especially in generating complex proofs. Adjust the temperature to explore more diverse outputs. Finally ensure that the MiniF2F problems are properly formatted.
